# ddev auth ssh (failed: exit status 1)

Tags: ddev

I cannot get `ddev auth ssh` working.

```
ddev auth ssh

Identity added: id_rsa (id_rsa)
Identity added: mid_rsa (mid_rsa)
Identity added: th_rsa (jx@x.local)
Docker command 'docker [run -it --rm --volumes-from=ddev-ssh-agent --user=501 --entrypoint= --mount=type=bind,src=/Users/xxx/.ssh,dst=/tmp/sshtmp drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.21.4-built bash -c cp -r /tmp/sshtmp ~/.ssh && chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh && cd ~/.ssh && ssh-add $(file * | awk -F: "/private key/ { print \$1 }")]' failed: exit status 1
```

Any help would be appreciated, power off didn't help.

- MacOs 13.2.1
- DDEV v1.21.4
- Docker 4.17.0

Comment: It's not clear what "not working" means? You don't show an error message or describe what "not working" means to you. You might want to look for things in your ~/.ssh directory that are not valid keys and remove them. Alternately, add your keys one at a time to find out which one causees the failure.

Comment: The last line showed the error. Thanks, removing all other stuf in  ~/.ssh helped, no more error "failed: exit status 1).
Now the key and config file is on the ddev .ssh folder. If I know try to `ddev exec ssh -v -L 8080:xxx.xx.xx.xx:8080 xxx@xxx.nl` it keeps still hanging on "Connecting to xxx.nl [xxx.xx.xx.xx] port 22.". On my Mac I can make the tunnel.

Comment: I make a new question for that

Comment: In my case the error was thrown because I use subfolders for ssh keys (`~/.ssh/customer/id_rsa`). So I had to modify the command to check the subfolders: `docker run -it --rm --volumes-from=ddev-ssh-agent --user=1000 --entrypoint= --mount=type=bind,src=/home/schnere/.ssh,dst=/tmp/sshtmp drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.21.5-built bash -c 'cp -r /tmp/sshtmp ~/.ssh && chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh && cd ~/.ssh && ssh-add $(file */* | awk -F: "/private key/ { print \$1 }")'`