# `ddev auth ssh` (failed: exit status 1)

Tags: docker, ssh, ddev

When I run `ddev auth ssh`, I see the following:

`Docker command 'docker [run -it --rm --volumes-from=ddev-ssh-agent --user=501 --entrypoint= --mount=type=bind,src=/Users/xxxx/.ssh,dst=/tmp/sshtmp drud/ddev-ssh-agent:v1.21.5-built bash -c cp -r /tmp/sshtmp ~/.ssh && chmod -R go-rwx ~/.ssh && cd ~/.ssh && ssh-add $(file * | awk -F: "/private key/ { print \$1 }")]' failed: exit status 1`

I'm new to most of this, so I know the error is trying to point me in the correct direction, but I'm fairly lost.

I appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

- MacOS 13.2.1
- DDEV v1.21.6

Tried:

- Based on [another recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75617145/ddev-auth-ssh-failed-exit-status-1), I tried removing everything in ~/.ssh, but that didn't help. I've reviewed many questions here on StackOverflow but not many people mention failing to `poweroff`.
- [This Github thread](https://github.com/ddev/ddev/issues/2625) told me what I did wrong, but I'm not clear how to undo this. I tried `poweroff` and reinstalling ddev via homebrew but nope, same error.

Expecting:
`ddev auth ssh` to execute normally

Comment: I don't think this had anything to do with not doing `ddev poweroff`, and DDEV will ask you to do that on `ddev start` after an upgrade anyway. I would just 1) do the poweroff, 2) restart Docker, 3) the problem is likely still that you have an invalid file or a non-key file in ~/.ssh. This probably requires a more interactive session than Stack Overflow can give, so join us in Discord, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k

Comment: Oh, and thank you so much for doing your research first!

Comment: Thanks for the advice, @rfay. I powered off and restarted Docker but no love. I'll join y'all on Discord if I don't get this sorted in my free time this week.

Comment: After trying many rabbit holes, I focused on #3 -- the ~/.ssh folder. I looked up the expected directory structure, and indeed, I was missing a few files. My last computer died, and I never ran `ssh-keygen` on the new one to produce a new `id_rsa` | `id_rsa.pub` key pair. Once I did that, `ddev auth ssh` executed without error. I hope this helps someone else. Thanks, @rfay, for the nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Yay, please write an answer explaining what the problem was and how you solved it. (Mostly, you hadn't run `ssh-keygen` to create the proper directory and you had no key at all I guess.) But I have to admit one question... Why were you even running `ddev auth ssh` if you didn't have ssh and keys set up? If you're not using ssh inside the container, you don't even need to do `ddev auth ssh`.

Comment: I must have had keys set up at some point because I recently SSH'd into my webhost. I go for long periods not using this side of my brain -- I need to consistently practice more so I don't lose track. Thanks for the help and feedback.

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the issue wasn't related to `ddev poweroff` after all.

Based on @rfay's suggestion, I took a closer look at the ~/.ssh folder and looked up the proper directory structure. The folder should have:

- authorized_keys
- config
- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pub
- known_hosts

In my case, I was missing private and public key files for some unknown reason.

I ran `ssh-keygen` to produce new `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files. I was then able to run `ddev auth ssh` without issue.

Comment: Can you file a bug ticket against ddev, please? While not having SSH keys is kind-of unusual for a developer, the tool shouldn't fail miserably in that case, but give an error that hints at the source.

Answer (score 0):

For pushing to pantheon, I found that I need to run ddev auth ssh, and then also manually run terminus auth:login. If I don't do the 2nd step, I keep getting requests to run ddev auth ssh even though apparently it is the terminus authorization that is the missing step.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).